# Show toast notification via Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications as admin throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, toast

Sending a toast notification as admin as recommended in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

Target Framework: net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0 (as required)

Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications: 7.1.3

Sending a toast notification as current user via Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications works fine.

e.g.

```
new ToastContentBuilder()
   .AddText("Toast notification as current user.")
   .Show();
```

If i add a manifest file to the project with `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` I get the exception: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Is there a way to call toast notification as admin?